# Synonym for "corollary" in English?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I am looking for a synonym (or near synonym) for *corollary* in English.

**Why?** I find it convenient to have the two words *theorem* and *proposition*, as I like to cite other people's results as "theorems" and my own results as "propositions". I'd like to use a similar dichotomy for corollaries.

Any ideas?

**Note:** In German, for instance, one could use *Korollar* and *Folgesatz* for this purpose. (And there are also the two words *Lemma* and *Hilfssatz*. How convenient!)

Comment: "consequence" is close

Comment: You might also get away with _implication_. On the other hand, you might want to change the occasional _proposition_ to _lemma_.

Comment: A fairly antiquated term is "porism". Although strictly this means the porism result follows  from the proof not the statement of another result. Strictly, Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem is a porism of Godel's original proof of his First Incompleteness Theorem, but not a corollary, because if you prove it using The Halting Problem, that won't get you anywhere.

Comment: This is kind of a matter of opinion. In Logic, it seems every mathematical statement that is provable is a theorem, but people like to choose relative terms to either upgrade or downgrade a theorem's importance in context. Theorems are named usually for big results with a lot of consequences (a.k.a. Corollaries), Propositions are usually quick theorems for useful facts like properties of derivatives, etc. And Lemmas are not necessarily short, but are theorems used in the proof of larger Theorems. So technically, in this light, Theorems would be Corollaries of Lemmas... it's a mess

Comment: @KevinS . And there are many results called "Paradox" ( Russell's , Simpson's, Burali - Forti, Euler - Cramer, Banach - Tarski, etc.) either because the usual proof is by contradiction, or because it seems wrong at first glance. And some very important results are traditionally called lemmas, e.g. Uryssohn's Lemma, Fodor's Lemma.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think paradoxes are worthy of another discussion! As for the big named Lemmas, I've definitely observed many of these and could never understand why they chose Lemma over Theorem when it was so central to a theory. I think there should be a convention for like locality of the terminology. That is, per document, the relative terms applied should be based on what is covered. But then this perhaps convolutes the search terms online etc.

Comment: @KevinS . In chess, if you are the first to write about an opening, it might get named after you, even if you wrote "Don't play this. It's bad."

Answer (score 2):

This is Soft Question, with no Exact "Correct" Answer.

With that comment, I suggest :

> [illation](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ILLATION) :
> The reasoning involved in **drawing a conclusion** or making a **logical judgment**
> on the basis of **circumstantial evidence** and **prior conclusions**
> rather than on the basis of **direct observation**

This is a Synonym of ( or a type of ) Corollary & you have 2 words to use in your Dichotomy.

Example Usage 1 :
We know :
Preposition OR Theorem : $\pi$ is transcendental.
Hence, without much further analysis, we can state :
Corollary OR **Illation** : $\pi^2$ is transcendental.

Example Usage 2 :
We know :
Preposition OR Theorem : Pythagoras : $A^2+B^2=C^2$ in a right-angle triangle.
Hence, without much further analysis, we can state :
Corollary OR **Illation** : Hypotenuse is the longest side in a right-angle triangle.

Answer (score 0):

In Sanskrit we use the word प्रमेयम् (Prameyam) for a theorem and उपप्रमेयम्(UpPrameyam) for a corollary. For example sometimes the Pythagoras Theorem is called the Baudhayan Prameyam as he conjectured it in 800 BC in Vedic India.

Now, observing the two words carefully, we observe that the two only differ by a prefix - उप( Up). This prefix generally means something that is secondary to the non prefixed word(example: Up+Rashtrapati or Vice-president).
Formally an Upprameyam is defined as a secondary Prameyam that aromatically gets validated when the original Prameyam is proved. It follows from the Premayam.

So, a few relevant terms in english using the above definition may be :
Consectary, Consequent, Consequence, and sometimes Porism.